# errors Installing google sheets in golang

Tags: go, go1.14

I'm trying to install google sheets for Go via the https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/go guide
when I issue:
`go get -u google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4`

I'm getting a error:

> cd C:\Users\Tomas\go\src\google.golang.org\genproto; git pull --ff-only
>   fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
>   package google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status: exit status 128

I'm using go version `go1.14.2` windows/amd64 on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Delete the package from GOPATH and go get it again. Your package is modified and git is refusing to pull from upstream.